# How to open Whatsapp from flutter application

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app.
I want to open (just open) WhatsApp from my app.

How can I open WhatsApp from my app and share image and text with my contacts?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install a package

```
url_launcher: ^6.1.5
```

Then make a function, it is different for android and iOS. You also need to check if the device is android or iOS. For that you can import library like:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

your function for opening whatsapp:

```
  openWhatsapp({required BuildContext context}) async {

String whatsapp = '+92******';
String whatsappURlAndroid = "whatsapp://send?phone=$whatsapp&text=hello";
String whatsappURLIos =
    "https://wa.me/$whatsapp?text=${Uri.parse("hello")}";
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappURLIos))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappURLIos));
  } else {
    _showToast(text: "whatsapp no installed");
  }
} else {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappURlAndroid))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappURlAndroid));
  } else {
    _showToast(text: "whatsapp no installed");
  }
}
```

}

Remember I have installed the package to show toasts

```
fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
```

and function for showing toasts:

```
  _showToast({required String text}) {
Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: text,
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
    backgroundColor: ColorConstants.roseColor,
    textColor: ColorConstants.whiteColor,
    fontSize: 16.0);
```

}

call the openWhatsapp function and you are ready to go.
Note: you need to add permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package

```
_launchURL() async {
    const url = "https://wa.me/?text=Your%20text%20here";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    }
  }
```

2nd option is [esys_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share/) plugin for sharing files & text with other applications.

Comment: I did it by using _launch, but stuck to open image in whatsapp. Will you please guide me how to open image in the code below.                                                                       onPressed: () => _launch('whatsapp://send?text=' +
                                  state.product.title +
                                  "\n" +
                                  state.product.description +
                                  "\n" +
                                  "Price: \$" +
                                  state.product.price.toString() ),

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of packages on pub.dev
Did you try this one https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_open_whatsapp ?

Comment: Thanks, but this plugin is for a single number only and I want to open WhatsApp select contact and send data that include text and images.